# Calling Java class in another class not working for me

Tags: java, cloudinary, ofbiz

I thought when Java classes are in the same directory, you don't need to import another class when you use it inside another.
I have this class that will initiate Cloudinary uploading of files back to the cloud, but when I call it inside another class and run build I get this error 'cannot access CloudinaryUpload'

The Cloudinary class

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.cloudinary.Cloudinary;
import com.cloudinary.utils.ObjectUtils;

public class CloudinaryUpload {

    public static void main(String arg[])throws Exception{
        Map config = ObjectUtils.asMap(
            "cloud_name", "name",
            "api_key", "api_key",
            "api_secret", "api_secret",
            "secure", true
        );
        Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary(config);
    }
}
```

Just a snippet of code of  another class where I am calling it

```java
public class ClientManagerServices {

    private static final int BYTES_DOWNLOAD = 1024;
    
    //The Cloudinary class
    private CloudinaryUpload cloudinaryUpload = CloudinaryUpload();
    public static String getMessageBody(Delegator delegator, String requester, String subject, String registryFileId, String clientId) {

        GenericValue fileData = null;
        GenericValue userData = null;
        GenericValue clientData = null;
        String bodyToReturn = "";

        try {
            fileData = delegator.findOne("RegistryFile", UtilMisc.toMap("registryFileId", registryFileId), false);
        } catch (GenericEntityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Cannot see the "package" declarations at the file tops. Take a careful look at your imports too that they match packaging levels properly.

Comment: `private CloudinaryUpload cloudinaryUpload = CloudinaryUpload();` In this, are you creating the object of `CloudinaryUpload` class, then _CloudinaryUpload()_ function is return the instance of that class or you forgot it?

Comment: yes I am creating the object  to access the cloudinary config

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5354987/samuel-marchant They just import at the top

Comment: You are not creating a class, you're calling a method `CloudinaryUpload()`, which does not exist. Did you mean to use `new CloudinaryUpload()`? As an aside the `main` method in `CloudinaryUpload` doesn't make sense to me, it doesn't really do anything. Do you maybe think that `CloudinaryUpload()` would somehow execute the `main` method (it does not, that is not how Java works).

Comment: Okay maybe I am not getting the gist of this java thing, How can I use the CloudinaryUpload inside ClientManagerServices class?

Comment: I wanted A reusable class that I can use multiple times

Comment: Then you shouldn't put things in main. Read any introductory Java text that covers object oriented programming. The local variables you define in main should probably be fields. Then you also need accessors or other methods that do something with those fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
private CloudinaryUpload cloudinaryUpload = CloudinaryUpload();
```

If that is supposed to creating new instance it should be

```
private CloudinaryUpload cloudinaryUpload = new CloudinaryUpload();
```

Note ... `new`.  If you leave out the `new`, then that is a call to a *method* named `CloudinaryUpload` ... and no such *method* exists in your code.

Comment: yes it should be a new instance

Comment: if they are in the same directory, is there any need of importing CloudinaryUpload class

Comment: It depends on what the package is.